# How to store all the ID's of all the selected checkboxes?

Tags: jquery, html

I have action drop box  calling the actionFunc()to do something

here is the actionFunc():

```
 <script language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function()
    {

        $("#paradigm_all").click(function()             
        {
            var checked_status = this.checked;
            $("input[name=notPaid]").each(function()
            {
                this.checked = checked_status;

            });

        });                 
    });

    function actionFunc(){
                var CHKcollect = [];

        CHKcollect.push($("input[name=notPaid]:checked").attr('id'));
        alert (CHKcollect);

        }


 </script>
```

here are the check boxes

```
<input  id="<separator>'.$user_id.'<separator>'.$orvalue.'<separator>'.$prodId.'<separator>" name="notPaid"  class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox"   onClick="notPAID(this.id)"  />
```

....... here is the select box

```
  <a><select  onchange="actionFunc()" id="itemselected" class="optselct"  >
           <option  value="Select" selected="selected">Select the action</option>
           <option value="pay">Pay for it</option>
           <option value="del">Delete it</option>
           <option value="mov">Move to waiting list</option>
      </select></a>
```

This function alerts only the first selected check box, not all the selected check boxes. 
What am I doing wrong here? I need to store all the ID's in an array to be parsed by json

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reference the `jQuery` docs for the `attr` function located [here](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), you will see that they state the following...

> Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of
>   matched elements or set one or more attributes for every matched
>   element.

The reason you're only getting the first element in the array is because of the this line..

```
CHKcollect.push($("input[name=notPaid]:checked").attr('id'));
```

You're only getting the attribute for the first element returned, not all of them.

You need to iterate over each element returned and get the attribute.

```
$("input[name=notPaid]:checked").each(function()
{
    CHKcollect.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: great help thanks, you are wonderful, I just don't understand why someone reply without reading the question at all.

Comment: could you up vote me, I don't know why someone down voted my question, appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
var CHKcollect = [];

$("input[name='notPaid']:checked").each(function(){
    CHKcollect.push(this.id);
});

alert(CHKcollect);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#itemselected').on('change', function()
            {
                var CHKcollect = [];

                $("input[name=notPaid]:checked").each(function() {

                    CHKcollect.push(this.id);


                });

                alert(CHKcollect);
            });
```

Check Working [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hardiksondagar/kx94E/)